# What anti/pattern involves repeatedly passing around the same parameters?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, parameters, refactoring

So let's say I have some code...

```
House = function () { /* constructor */ }

House.childPlay  (childId) { ... }
House.childLearn (childId) { ... }
House.childEat   (childId) { ... }
```

So, implicitly, this House object "has" children, but it doesn't necessarily have Child objects, yet. Which is what I'm wondering. That constant passing around of childId seems fishy. Should House just **Have** a collection of Child objects?

```
House.Child.play  () { ... }
House.Child.learn () { ... }
House.Child.eat   () { ... }
```

My only concern is that some of the operations sit in between the House and Child, like they interact. So, the Child object would need some sort of awareness of the parent object.

```
House.Child.clean () {
    self._cleaningStrategy( self.house._provideMop() );
}
```

I see there's a design pattern called the Parameter Object. Is that this? I think it would be if I was passing a tuple's worth of parameters, but here I'm only passing around one.

Comment: So, what is your concern? How is passing this id impacting your code?

Comment: An equally valid question may be "why doesn't a house belong to a child?" ...but you haven't told us why that can't be the case. Guess it's 'cause kids have no money.

Comment: Yes, that constantly passing around the same parameter is too verbose/clumsy and that there's a better way.

Comment: @SanJacinto There isn't anything preventing a Child from Having a House. I just haven't implemented it yet and that's exactly what I'm asking about. There's no restriction.

Comment: Question is __impossible__ to answer. Imaginary non code related examples are difficult to discuss. Real examples more likely attract real answers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the behavior of a child is independent from the house (and it should be). If we want the child to eat, that has nothing to do with the house, so this would be the way to go:

```
Child.Eat();
```

If we want the child to clean a house, it sounds like we should do this:

```
Child.CleanHouse(house);
```

This way, the child can also possibly clean another house; not just the one house.

CleanHouse() could look like this:

```
Mop mop = house.GetMop();
// Perform cleaning activities here.
```

I agree with your concern of having Child behavior on the house object. That's violating the OOP Single Responsibility Principle (house should only do house stuff), and the design idea of *Information Expert* (the class that has the information necessary to fulfill the responsibility). House should contain behavior specific to a house, and Child should contain behavior specific to a child, otherwise they're too tightly coupled.

I don't know that this is a design pattern issue so much as it's an OOP issue.

Comment: I guess that's better than House.EatChild(). :o)

Comment: In some horror movies I'm pretty sure houses eat children. Not unheard of!